# What are the best resources for ASP.NET + C#?

Tags: c#, asp.net, resources, reference

Edit: (Being more concise to avoid rubbing up against other questions)

I see the link for some suggested books... Books are good but I prefer the web. I can try them out free right away. And I'm a guy that likes multiple sources of information either way.

I am also a big believer in tutorials over just reading. Something I can try out and then modify or do my own way. (I just made a blog in PHP/Zend since that was originally going to be the project language)

And I didn't see what made the best references (which is in my mind entirely different from a learning resource). Though I'm sure I'll figure this out naturally as I google issues that crop up.

Comment: must be a many times duplicate

Comment: Sorry, but this is definitely "Overly broad" ASP.Net and C# are both massive subjects, and the intersection of the two isn't much smaller. If you like books then check [Best book on ASP.NET 3.5 (C#) programming?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276229/best-book-on-asp-net-3-5-c-programming), if you like the web then just Google search the area that you are interested in.

Comment: one of many: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/276229/best-book-on-asp-net-3-5-c-programming

Comment: `Hopefully this will stay open` - not likely. It is subjective, and SO is not meant to be the place where you ask extremely broad questions like this. What might be more appropriate is to look at editing the `asp.net` tag wiki and add some references there for others to see.

Comment: Hopefully my edit made it more clear what I'm looking for. Anyways, the fact that you linked to a popular thread on the best book shows that my post can't be too egregious.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another good resource is [4GuysFromRolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202742/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/).

Microsoft has a [Beginners' Learning Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/beginner/default.aspx).

For paid training, Pluralsight (mentioned above) and [TekPub](http://tekpub.com/) are both highly rated.

Answer (score 6):

There's this website called Stackoverflow that's pretty good

Comment: One I intend to use but I am pretty certain that if I used it as my only learning resource I'd get banned before my 10th or 20th question...

Answer (score 4):

According to MS: http://www.asp.net/
Theres also channel 9: http://channel9.msdn.com/

Comment: i agree this is a good place to get started on the web.

Answer (score 1):

I enjoy Pluralsight's video offerings and [TechEd](http://www.msteched.com/) online videos.